# Как сделать правильно авторизацию на сервлетах

Tags: java, java-ee

Я разбираюсь с темой сервлетов, на данный момент сделал jsp страничку, на которой расположены поля для авторизации, после ввода логина и пароля я делаю POST запрос другому сервлету, который идёт в БД посредством JDBC, и в зависимости от привилегий пользователя перенаправляет его на другую jsp страницу. Но где правильнее ходить в БД, в сервлете или в фильтре, а уже результат предавать в сервлет? Или сразу в jsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно сервлеты, точнее web-приложения опираются на стандартный механизм аутентификации, который предоставляет контейнер (сервер-приложений). Практически все сервера позволяют задать авторизацию через базу данных.
Кроме встроенных способов проверки логина предоставляется возможность разработать собственный модуль, если стандартные чем-то не устраивают.
Эти модули (стандартные и собственной разработки) срабатывают до фильтров.
Если взбрело в голову сделать что-то подобное по возможностям со стандартным механизмам авторизации, то очевидно лучше сделать это в фильтрах.
Например очень популярный нестандартный секурити-фреймворк Apache Shiro встраивается в web-приложение как фильтр. Если EE (ejb там всякие) не нужно, то можете смело использовать shiro. Но с компонентами EE, на сколько мне известно, он не дружит. Так бы и сам применял.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с БД используют обычно DAO-слой. В общем случае это классы, осуществляющие запрос в базу и возвращающие результат этих запросов. При поступлении запроса на сервлет параметры запроса обрабатываются при помощи обращения к методам DAO и формируется соответствующий ответ клиенту. Про DAO можете почитать например [тут](http://www.dokwork.ru/2014/02/daotalk.html)

Comment: ну я в сервлете вызываю объект, который собственно работает с БД, т.е. тот же DAO ... просто вопрос - где вызывать этот объект и работать с ним..

Comment: Может кодом поделитесь, что именно смущает. А то непонятно пока, в чем проблема

Comment: да там каша, не хочу тратить ваше время, banme впринципе уже ответил на мой вопрос